# google calendar, spreadsheet and script handle time zone differently

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I am trying to write a script to add events from Spreadsheet to Calendar. I found the time of added events is always 1 hour off. I checked the time zone settings and here's what I found.

Calendar:    (GMT-04:00) Eastern Time
Spreadsheet: (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time
Script:      (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time

So they are all Eastern Time, but the Calendar uses the Daylight Savings Time while the Spreadsheet and Script.

I know I can manually adjust GMT every time DST changes so that the resulting time is right. But is there a better way, so that I can set and forget?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoding the timezone with GMT-04:00 use the literal expression of your geographic area (aka Canonical ID) as defined in this standard : [Joda.org](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html)

this is what Google Apps Script is using.

You can also get that more simply using

`SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`

or from the calendar object : `calendar.getTimeZone()`

all these parameters will handle daylight savings automatically, which is not the case for the GMT+xx:xx method.

You shouldn't have any problem as long as both are on the same timezone. Calendars have a `setTimeZone(timeZone)` method and spreadsheets have a `setSpreadsheetTimeZone(timeZone)` method so it is easy to synchronize both

---

### EDIT

Following comment

Since you seem to combine date and time in a unique date object and that the daylight saving puts you into trouble (because "pure time" values in spreadsheets are converted to a date JavaScript object automatically and with summer time correction), below is a small code that I use to workaround this issue. I added a few logs to show intermediate values;

```
function combineDateAndTime(){
  // in this example cell A1 has a date and cell B1 has time
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var dateOnly = sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var timeOnly = sh.getRange('B1').getValue();
  Logger.log('dateOnly object is : '+dateOnly+'\ntimeOnly object is : '+timeOnly);
  var hours = Number(Utilities.formatDate(timeOnly, 'GMT'+timeOnly.toString().split('GMT')[1],'hh'));
  var minutes = timeOnly.getMinutes();
  var completeDateAndTime = new Date(dateOnly.setHours(hours,minutes,0,0));
  Logger.log('completeDateAndTime is : '+completeDateAndTime);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Note : there are other ways to retrieve hour values, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715841/gas-how-to-read-the-correct-time-values-form-google-spreadsheet/17727300#17727300) for example.

Comment: That's because December 1899 was not in summer !!! In JavaScript there is no time value without date, it's always a complete date and time value. You'll have to take care of that in your script.

Comment: Both Calendar and Spreadsheet is in American/New_York time zone, but different GMT: Calendar GMT-0400, Spreadsheet GMT-0500.

In the Spreadsheet, I have a cell formatted as time '9:30' (values[1]). 
<code>var time1 = new Date(values[1]);</code>  
 <code>Logger.log('time1: ' + time1);</code>  
<code>// I will get: </code>  
<code>// time1: Sat Dec 30 1899 09:30:00 GMT-0500 (EST)</code>  

When I add events using this time to the calendar, it becomes 10:30, because the calendar is GMT-0400 (EDT).