# Google sheets DATEVALUE parameter cannot be parsed to date/time

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, array-formulas

I want to parse the following string as a datetime value in Google sheets:

```
10/04/2021 14:25:49 GMT+0430
```

But I get a parse error:

```
DATEVALUE parameter '10/04/2021 14:25:49 GMT+0430' cannot be parsed to date/time.
```

I am, however, able to convert the above string to datetime object using JavaScript and Apps Scripts in Google Sheets. So I don't think I have made a mistake in my datetime formatting. Are there any ways to make Google Sheets parse the above value natively?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datetime with timezone in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719851/datetime-with-timezone-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the parse error is coming from the inclusion of the timezone. See [Datetime with timezone in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39719851/11693593) for more information (it looks like you've already discovered that JavaScript and Apps Scripts works).