# How to conditionally change a date based on a time? Time zone differences?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using two functions to extract both the date & time out of a string:

**Raw String in DATA!A2:**
2022-03-06T04:52:33.813Z

`=LEFT(DATA!$A$2,FIND("T",DATA!$A$2)-1)` to reformat a string into a date:

**Result:**
2022-03-06

In another cell I am extracting the time and converting it to USA CT time:
`=MID(DATA!$A$2,12,5)-"6:00"`

**Result:** 10:52 PM

---

**The Issue:**

I have successfully subtracted 6 hours to convert this time to CT, but now whenever the time is on or after 6 PM CT, the date (2022-03-06) prematurely advances to the next day. In the example above, because 10:52 PM is after 6 PM, the date should be showing 2022-03-05.

Are there any ways to check if the time is after 6 PM, and if that is TRUE, to correct the date by -1 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A-

Try, without any script

```
=value(left(A1,10))+value(mid(A1,12,12))
```

[image]

### B-

If you want to subtract 6 hours, try

```
=value(left(A1,10))+value(mid(A1,12,12))-6/24
```

you will change the date if any

### C-

However, to solve that issue `I have successfully subtracted 6 hours to convert this time to CT, but now whenever the time is on or after 6 PM CT, the date (2022-03-06) prematurely advances to the next day.`

1- check the timezone of your spreadsheet

2- AND the timezone of your script editor.

To do that in script editor, check the parameters

- click on the gear in the left hand side) and check the third parameter
- go back to the scripts
- modifie time zone in `appscript.json` and make sure it is the same as your spreadsheet (for instance `Europe/paris`)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Both answers would have been a solution but I prefer not having to use a script if it can be done with the right formula. Genius work on the subtracting of 6 hours in this "Date Time" format... that was very much needed, rather than having the fields separate. I also split the date & time into two separate fields afterwards as @ale13 suggested. Thank you Mike!

Answer (score 1):

*Since Google Sheets does not recognize the raw string as a date, the best option for this would actually be to create a custom function which converts the string into a date. In this way, it will be easier to perform the date operations you want.*

---

To do so, you will have to go to *Extensions* > *Apps Script* and use the following code for the custom function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719851/datetime-with-timezone-in-google-sheets):

```
/**
 * Converts a string to a date-time value
 * @customfunction
 */
function DATETIME(dateTimeString) {
  var output = new Date (dateTimeString);
  if(!isNaN(output.valueOf())) {
    return output;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Not a valid date-time');
  }   
}
```

Save the project, run it, authorize the script and return to the sheet.

Afterwards, in your sheet, call the `DATETIME` function as you would with an already existing Sheets function and subtract the hours using the `TIME` function:

```
=(DATETIME(A2)-TIME(7,0,0))
```

Assuming your sheet looks like this, the resulting column will look like this:

[image: result sheet]

If you also want to separate the date from the time, you will have to add two more formulae (assuming that `D1` contains the result from the `DATETIME` custom function):

- For retrieving the date:

```
=LEFT(D1,FIND(" ",D1)-1)
```

- For retrieving the time:

```
=RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-FIND(" ",D1))
```

After all the formulae, this is how the sheet will look like:

[image: end result after applying all the formulae]

#### Reference

- [Datetime with timezone in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719851/datetime-with-timezone-in-google-sheets);
- [TIME Sheets Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093056);
- [LEFT Sheets Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079);
- [RIGHT Sheets Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087).