# Google Apps Script add some weird time

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I try to get time form table it plus 29 mins and 43 secs constantly

```
function onEdit(e){  

var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("h8ueab6ooel3iv8c7v4nd6bkvg@group.calendar.google.com");
Logger.log(cal)
// var arrayDate, arrayTimeStart, arrayTimeEnd;
var DateStart = new Date();
var DateEnd = new Date();
var table = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var dlinna = table.getLastRow();
  var data = table.getRange("A2:E"+dlinna).getValues();
  
   
  for (var i=data.length-1; i<data.length;i++){
    Logger.log(data[i][2]);
       
  }
}
```

[the given row][image: 1]

[the weird time][image: 2]

Comment: It looks like the code is trying to turn a duration into a date

Comment: Related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715841/how-to-read-the-correct-time-duration-values-from-google-spreadsheet